# Strategies Behind Differential Subscription Pricing Across Countries Despite Server Costs

Tags: internationalization, cloud

I've noticed significant differences in Duolingo subscription prices across various countries, with rates being notably lower in some regions. Considering the potential for higher server costs due to cloud usage in these countries, how do companies manage to maintain affordability in their pricing models?

[image]

Here's a breakdown of the pricing for both individual and family packages in countries like the US, UK, Canada, Turkey, Vietnam, Thailand, and Indonesia, showcasing the disparities. Given that the cost for cloud servers might be on par with or exceed those in the US, what strategies or factors contribute to the ability to offer such reduced prices in these markets?

Could the reason be that the overall cost per user is generally less than $1, allowing companies to sustain smaller profits in developing countries while securing larger margins in developed regions?